# Pandas get list of all data types in object dtype

Tags: python, pandas

From experimenting it seems to me that Pandas stores a column with multiple datatypes (e.g. str and float) as object datatype. Is there a one-liner Pandas command to check whether the datatype in this object column are actually all the same? Since str is stored in Pandas as object, sometimes if I get a column with object datatype then I automatically assume all entries are strings, and I apply str methods to the column and obtain seemingly correct but actually wrong values.

Comment: `pd.Series(['a',1]).apply(type).nunique()` gives 2 , you can probably compare if it equals 1 in your case.. but again it may differ for your actual usecase, it is better if you can create an example for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @anky that's perfect; thank you very much!